# Hive - Convert epoch time (ms - 13 digit) to timestamp till milliseconds in hive sql

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, hortonworks-data-platform, epoch

I need to get completed timestamp from epoch timestamp in hive query.

```
For example 
epoch time      --- 1606407266850
timestamp value --- 2020-11-26 21:44:26 
expected value  --- 2020-11-26 21:44:26.850
```

My method in hive:

```
Select timestamp(concat(from_unixtime(CAST(lastModifiedOn AS BIGINT),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'),".",CAST(lastModifiedOn AS BIGINT)%1000),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS')
from db.table1
```

**My question:** Do we have better approach to get timestamp value till millisecond? we can easily get value till second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select cast(lastModifiedOn/1000 as timestamp);
```

Can't specify the precision but will keep the timestamp up to the highest precision

Comment: Thanks mck, please find below comment
`select 
cast(cast('1606407266850' AS BIGINT)/1000 as timestamp) ms,-- Giving correct results with ms (2020-11-26 16:14:26.85 )
cast(cast('1606476624' AS BIGINT) as timestamp) sec; -- wrong results (1970-01-19 14:14:36.624)`  Can we do something aboue epoch time second

Comment: Standard epoch time is based on seconds. Your non-standard epoch time of 1606407266850 is based on milliseconds, but 1606476624 is based on seconds. You can't have a formula that calculates the correct timestamp for both of the values, unless you do a `case when`